# Creating a signed subordinate CA for client certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificates

I have a root self-signed CA which I've created for myself. With this CA (we'll call it `country`), I've created a server certificate and key for my webserver, nginx.

I now would like to create a second CA, `state` which will be used as my `ssl_client_certificate` CA in nginx. I'd like to keep `state` and `country` separated for various reasons and not use my root CA `country` for directly signing client certificates.

How can I generate a certificate authority `state` which is signed by `country` for authenticating client certificates in nginx?

Comment: I personally use [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) for managing certs/keys. It's cross platform and allows tons of control. I don't like managing CAs through the openssl command line because it requires managing an `openssl.cnf` file (I much prefer specifying all args on the command itself). However there appears to be a nice writeup [here](https://jamielinux.com/articles/2013/08/create-an-intermediate-certificate-authority/). If you're interested in an answer for XCA, I can put one together.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. OpenSSL from the commandline is a bit of a nightmare if you're doing anything more advanced like managing a chain of certificates. Thanks for the tip, everything's now working.